# Detect and log IP address

Tags: windows, ip, router

My home network gets a dynamic IP address from the provider. I want to log that. How can I obtain "my" IP address (not that of my machine but of my router) and log that to a file, so I can get a list of used IP addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a curl request to : https://api.ipify.org/

```
curl 'https://api.ipify.org'
```

You have some examples in some languages here : https://www.ipify.org/ ( scroll to "examples" )

Comment: On Windows with Git's curl.exe I had to remove the quotes around the URL to get it working.